# WSO2 esb UDP to TCP conversion in high rate

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am doing UDP to HTTP transformation with WSO2 esb with following proxy config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="UDPProxy"
       transports="udp"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="http://127.0.0.1:9764"/>
         <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2"/>
      </endpoint>
   </target>
   <parameter name="transport.udp.port">9998</parameter>
   <parameter name="transport.udp.contentType">text/plain</parameter>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

And then I have a simple java http server program running on port 9764. So it just listen to the port and log number of received message count for every 5 seconds.

I tested above proxy with UDP messages (10 udp messages per second) and it worked well. Then I tried with 100 UDP messages per second and after while I can see following log on ESB console.

```
[2016-05-02 12:04:45,160]  WARN - TargetHandler http-outgoing-2426: Connection time out while in state: REQUEST_DONE
[2016-05-02 12:04:45,163]  WARN - SynapseCallbackReceiver Synapse received a response for the request with message Id : urn:uuid:101bdbc5-e5fa-4c35-8aa1-    525060b55dec But a callback is not registered (anymore) to process this response
[2016-05-02 12:04:45,163]  WARN - TargetHandler http-outgoing-2399: Connection time out while in state: REQUEST_DONE
[2016-05-02 12:04:45,165]  WARN - SynapseCallbackReceiver Synapse received a response for the request with message Id : urn:uuid:4197a771-8b6d-4d82-bf39-87710c0c18d2 But a callback is not registered (anymore) to process this response
```

I am not sure why above warning appear. Could someone help me on this? 
Also I assume the connection between this pxoxy and my http client is HTTP NIO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ESB is waiting for a response from your endpoint (127.0.0.1:9764) but fall in timeout.
After this timeout, the ESB receive a response but it's too late, your callback (outSequence) does not exist any more.

If you use HTTP NIO, have a look to *repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml*, search for the http transportSender ant configure "SO_TIMEOUT", sample for 2 minutes : `<parameter name="SO_TIMEOUT">120000</parameter>`

If you need a longer timeout, you have to change *synapse.global_timeout_interval* in *repository/conf/synapse.properties*

Comment: Can I disable this and ask ESB to not to wait for response ?

Comment: I just figure that you've set OUT_ONLY to true in your inSequence, the ESB should not wait for a reponse from your endpoint, but if it receive such a response, you will have a warn that say that there is no callback receiver... I don't know why there is "Connection time out while in state: REQUEST_DONE"